# If column will only have 2 values, what kind of an index do I need to create for it

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

```js
var User = new Schema({
    gender: { type: String, index: true }
})
```

Will the above suffice to create an index on the gender column, which will only have 2 possible values?

Why not a `sparse` index?

Comment: Will you often run queries where the only filtered field is gender?

Comment: yes, why does that matter?

Comment: A query that will return 50% of the data may not be improved much by an index, and may actually run better without one.

Comment: Can you write an answer explaining your reasoning?

Comment: Actually, it gender will most often not be the only filter and it will certainly not return 50% of the data

Comment: If more fields than gender will be queried, additional fields in the index will improve performance.  Multiple documents are stored in leaf pages, if the `{gender:1}` index is the only index that can support the query, it will need to load every page with a matching gender from disk.  This will likely mean reading the entire collection from disk, even if it only has to examine half of the documents.

Comment: Well, given that it will not be only field in the query, and thus making an index will improve performance, what is the proper index type to make it?

Comment: That is a very big topic, and depends on the structure of the documents and nature of the query.  A good place to start might be https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/